# Redirect Image to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect an image path to my website homepage:

```
https://www.domainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/infographic.png
```

to

```
www/domainname.com.
```

I was trying to do it with the code below

```
# WPhtc: Begin Custom htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/wp-admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2017/03/.+?\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$ /home [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# WPhtc: End Custom htaccess
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What is `/home` meant to be? Don't you mean just `/` instead?

Comment: And what _exactly_ do you mean by "its not working"?

Comment: I mean when I https://domainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/infographic.png  it is not redirecting to homepage

Comment: Does it redirect somewhere else? Or do you get an error? Does nothing happen at all? Does the universe implode? _Be precise!_

Comment: Nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is the simplified rule set what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://[^/]+/wp-admin/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/uploads/\d+/\d+/ / [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect all requests to something inside those upload folders to the base URL of your site.

---

Obviously if you only want to redirect from that specific folder this also is possible:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://[^/]+/wp-admin/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ / [R=301,L]
```

And you certainly can also limit that logic to certain file name extensions only:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://[^/]+/wp-admin/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/uploads/2017/03/[^/]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$ / [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: @DevenderKumar First: that server is an `nginx` installation. How does that match with your `.htaccess` style file and question?

Comment: @DevenderKumar Second: I _am_ forwarded to the base URL, however with some strange steps. It looks like some other rewriting process cuts in. Just open your browsers console, select the network tab and see the response headers you get for that request you posted.

Comment: Sir i am new in Wordpress and don't have any idea how to solve this issue is there any way to do it  ?? Thanks

Comment: @DevenderKumar I modified the rule set again. Could you please do another test?

Comment: It is still same

Comment: @DevenderKumar The redirection _does_ work for me now. Note however that your example URL you gave in your own comment above is probably not what you expected! `ukwebhostreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/infographic.p‌​ng` contains a strange UTF-8 sequence in the file name extension. Replace it by a clean ".png" and try again. I see a clean redirection on your site for that.